# jQuery Isotope Filtering Modifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am working with Isotope and trying to create a menu system that dynamically filters content while also altering the submenu content, depending on the option that you've selected in the previous menu.

My current JSFiddle shows the topmost menu, along with the full content. When you select an option, the appropriate submenu appears. However, the 'active' status of the topmost menu does not change to reflect the item you've selected, nor does the content update to show the filter you've selected.

For my example, I am using grade levels and topics of study. It starts with you selecting one of either K (Kindergarten), G1 (Grade One), G2 (Grade Two), or choosing to display 'any' grade level. When you select 'K' for instance, a submenu is shown that has subject options. The content **should** update to show only items matching the 'kinder' class but remains showing all the content. Only when I click on the subtopic does it narrow.

1. **How can I make it update the content with each button press?**
2. **How can I enable the 'active' for the button press on the topmost level?**
3. **If enabling active for the topmost button does not enable it, how can I make 'any' work again to show all results (effectively reseting the selection)?**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sheldond/44ubdbvx/21/

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
  $('#kinder_filter').click(function() {
    $('#kinder_group').show();
    $('#g1_group').hide();
    $('#g2_group').hide();
    return false;
  });
  $('#g1_filter').click(function() {
    $('#g1_group').show();
    $('#kinder_group').hide();
    $('#g2_group').hide();
    return false;
  });
  $('#g2_filter').click(function() {
    $('#g2_group').show();
    $('#kinder_group').hide();
    $('#g1_group').hide();
    return false;
  }); 
});

$(document).ready( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.curriculum-dive'
  });

  // store filter for each group
  var filters = {};

  $('.filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // combine filters
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="filters">

  <div class="ui-group">
    <h3>Grade</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="grade_level">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".kinder" id="kinder_filter">K</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g1" id="g1_filter">G1</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g2" id="g2_filter">G2</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-group" id="kinder_group" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Kinder</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="kinder">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".kinder, .art">Art</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".kinder, .math">Math</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".kinder, .science">Science</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".kinder, .history">History</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-group" id="g1_group" style="display: none;">
    <h3>G1</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="g1">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g1, .art">Art</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g1, .math">Math</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g1, .science">Science</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g1, .history">History</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g1, .music">Music</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-group" id="g2_group" style="display: none;">
    <h3>G2</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="g2">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g2, .art">Art</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g2, .math">Math</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g2, .science">Science</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g2, .history">History</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g2, .music">Music</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".g2, .music">Spanish</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="curriculum-dive kinder art" style="background-color:red;">K-ART #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 art" style="background-color:green;">G1-ART #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 art" style="background-color:green;">G1-ART #2</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 art" style="background-color:green;">G1-ART #3</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 math">G2-MATH #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 fla" style="background-color:green;">G1-FLA #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 science" style="background-color:green;">G1-SCIENCE #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive kinder ecs" style="background-color:red;">K-ECS #2</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 science" style="background-color:green;">G1-SCIENCE #2</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 math">G2-MATH #2</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 science">G2-SCIENCE #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 science" style="background-color:green;">G1-SCIENCE #3</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive k history" style="background-color:red;">K-HISTORY #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 history" style="background-color:green;">G1-HISTORY #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 history">G2-HISTORY #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 music" style="background-color:green;">G1-MUSIC #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g1 music" style="background-color:green;">G1-MUSIC #2</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 music">G2-MUSIC #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 spanish">G2-SPANISH #1</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive k art" style="background-color:red;">K-ART #3</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive k art" style="background-color:red;">K-ART #4</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 music">G2-MUSIC #2</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive k art" style="background-color:red;">K-ART #5</div>
  <div class="curriculum-dive g2 music">G2-MUSIC #3</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help. JS is not my forte but I am working on it!